# JQuery My function only runs once

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to make that function that selects a random place and shows it when prompted. When pressing the button it only runs once.

```
$(".place").hide();

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*44);



$("#button").click(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#place"+randomNumber).show("slow", function(){
        alert=("New Place");
    });
});
```

Comment: You only generate the random number once. Are you just asking why the number doesn't change?

Comment: is there ant element exists with  $("#place"+randomNumber);

Comment: Yes basically I would like to be able to press the button an infinite number of times and have a different answer. I have tried setting a loop, but for some reason it does not work!

Comment: yes on the html all my propositions have a class called place

Comment: Can you add the relevant section of html to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a new  random number for each click

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    "use strict";
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*44);
    $("#place"+randomNumber).show("slow", function(){
        alert=("New Place");
    });
});
```

If you want the others to be hidden modify to:

```
$('.place').hide().filter("#place"+randomNumber).show...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only set `randomNumber` once. In order to generate new random numbers whenever the user clicks on your `#button`, you can make `randomNumber` a function:

```
$(".place").hide();

function randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*44);
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    "use strict";
    $("#place"+ randomNumber()).show(
    "slow", function(){
        alert=("New Place");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your randomNumber will always be the same once defined.
Move it inside the click handler.

```
$(".place").hide();

$("#button").click(function() {
    "use strict";
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*44); // <---
    $("#place"+randomNumber).show("slow", function(){
        alert=("New Place");
    });
});
```